# Disabling two finger scrolling in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, safari

I am developing a site where I disabled regular scrolling simply using **overflow: hidden;** so the user has to click through the nav to interact with each part. I was testing the mobile view on an iphone X using safari and discovered you can bypass that using two finders to scroll. Is there a CSS or JavaScript workaround to disable that function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: clip` instead of `overflow: hidden;`. As explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> Like for `hidden`, the content is clipped to the element's padding box. The difference between `clip` and `hidden` is that the `clip` keyword also forbids all scrolling, including programmatic scrolling.